# Working with classes, NSMutableString, and Release

Tags: class, objective-c++

I am having trouble accessing and clearing a NSMutableString pointer in other classes. In the Overlay.mm, I update a build out the string into a document that the Wrapper.mm needs to post to a webservice.

I need help with the syntax for hitting the Overlay methods. Also, it is not clear if I need to create a getter and setter in Overlay, if I need to synthesize the string, or what.

Simplified code:

Overlay.h

```
class Overlay : public BundleOverlay {

public:

Overlay(void);

    void ReleaseText();
    NSMutableString *StringBuilderDoc;

etc...
```

Overlay.mm

```
Overlay::Overlay(void)
{
    StringBuilderDoc = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
};

void Overlay::ReleaseText(){
     [StringBuilderDoc release];
}

void Overlay::UpdateText(BundleOverlayTracker *t)
{
[StringBuilderDoc appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s %ld %f\r", t[0], t[1], t[2];
}
```

Wrapper.mm

```
etc...
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ etc...", StringBuilderDoc];

[Overlay ReleaseText];
```

This is where the problem is. I want to read the StringBuilderDoc var and do more work in the post var.

Then, I want to clear and release it because I am done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call is invalid, as it's a C++ method, not an Objective-C method (and it's not a class method either):

```
[Overlay ReleaseText];
```

instead you would simply call it like this:

```
overlayInstance.ReleaseText();     // Where overlayInstance is the Overlay instance
```

(however note that it's conventional to name this method `releaseText()`).

You should also set the value to `nil` to avoid double-releasing the object (sending a message to a `nil` Objective-C is silently ignored):

```
void Overlay::ReleaseText(){
     [StringBuilderDoc release];     // Remove this if using ARC
     StringBuilderDoc = nil;
}
```

You will also want to add a call to `ReleaseText()` in the class destructor.

Also it's conventional to name that instance variable:

```
_stringBuilderDoc
```

Further notes: I am assuming you are not using ARC; if you are the compiler will tell you quickly enough about the invalid use of `release`, and instead you can remove the call to `release` and just set it to `nil` to release it.

Comment: I get an error "Use of undeclared identifier ReleaseText" in Wrapper.mm. Also how do I read StringBuilderDoc in Wrapper.mm it says, "did you mean Overlay::StringBuilderDoc." When I change it to that, it says, "Invalid Use of non-static data member StringBuilderDoc"

Comment: @User970008 Ah I understand.  Please tell me what reference you have to the `Overlay` object in `Wrapper.mm`.  I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @User970008 Yes if `overlay` is an allocated instance of `Overlay`, that looks right. Don't forget you'll need to call `delete overally;` in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: @User970008 I don't understand where the lambda will be used.